# Quarkus Mockito for chain responsibility pattern is null for validators

Tags: java, mockito, quarkus, junit5

I have a quarkus service where some validations are done in CDI beans using a design pattern approach of chain responsibility pattern.

Below are my classes.

My Service class whose method I am trying to mock.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Inject
    ValidatorChain validatorChain;

    @Inject
    ValidatorA va;
    @Inject
    ValidatorB vb;
    @Inject
    ValidatorC vc;

    // Method I am trying to mock

    public Optional<?> applyRaf(UpdateR updateR) {
        va.setNextValidator(vb);
        vb.setNextValidator(vc);

        validatorChain.setFirstValidator(va);
        // after above line in quarkus mockito firstValidator is always null, which I am
        // trying to solve
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

Now my validator chain design is.

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ValidatorChain {
    private CodeValidator firstValidator;

    public void setFirstValidator(CodeValidator firstValidator) {
        this.firstValidator = firstValidator;
    }

    public CodeValidator getFirstValidator() {
        return firstValidator;
    }

    public boolean validate(CheckME checkme) {
        if (firstValidator == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return firstValidator.validate(checkme);
    }

}
```

Now below are my examples of validators impls

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ValidatorA implements CodeValidator {
     //some validations
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ValidatorB implements CodeValidator {
     //some validations
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ValidatorC implements CodeValidator {
     //some validations
}
```

Here comes the Quarkus logic for testing

```java
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

@QuarkusTest
class CodeTest {

    @Nested
    class ApplyUpdateCases {
        @Mock
        ValidatorA va;
        @Mock
        ValidatorB vb;
        @Mock
        ValidatorC vc;

        @InjectMocks
        ValidatorChain validatorChain;
        @InjectMocks
        MyService rafservice = Mockito.mock(ServiceImpl.class);

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this); // initialize mocks

            va = Mockito.mock(ValidatorA.class);

            validatorChain.setFirstValidator(va);
        }

        // this is my test method

        @Test
        public void testValidateSelfRAF() {
    
                Mockito.when(rafservice.createRaf(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getTestRaf());
                var rafCreate = rafservice.createRaf(getTestCreate());
                var rafUpdate = getTestUpdate();
                Mockito.when(rafservice.find(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getTestRaf());
    
                rafUpdate.getRf().setCustomerId(rafCreate.getCustomerId());
    
                Mockito.when(rafservice.applyRaf(rafUpdate)).thenCallRealMethod();
    
                RafException ex = assertThrows(RafException.class, () - > rafservice.applyRaf(rafUpdate));
            }
    }
}
```

Now problem with this approach in QUARKUS Mockito is the method:

```
setFirstValidator
```

Never works, its always null hence validations code coverage is skipped.

My libraries used for mocking are:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-mockito")
}
```

Now what can I do so that setFirstValidator is called/mocked hence the validator class can be tested/covered in mockito

Comment: That "above line" is never executed, because your service is a mock. A mock doesn't have any code and does not execute your original code. Why are you mocking your SUT?

Comment: I think I am able to solve the problem using 
@InjectSpy over the validators

Comment: @Qasim it would be useful for future readers if you added your solution in the answers section